# Why do strftime() and date() show different timezones in PHP?

Tags: php, timezone

What is the reason of *strftime()* and *date()* functions of PHP are giving different time zones in the same script?

After setting the default timezone to UTC (using *date_default_timezone_set()* function), I have the following results:

```
strftime('%z') gives +0300
date('O') gives +0000
```

I wrote the  piece of code for testing purposes, so you can run it on your machine if you want:

```
<?php
$current_time = time();
$br = "<br />\n";


print   'Script has been executed on ' . date('Y.m.d H:i:s O', $current_time) . ' (<i>date(O)</i>)' . $br .
    $br .
    'ini_get(\'date.timezone\'): ' . ini_get('date.timezone') . $br .
    'date_default_timezone_<b>get</b>(): ' . date_default_timezone_get() . $br .
    '/etc/localtime: <b>' . exec('/bin/ls -l /etc/localtime|/usr/bin/cut -d"/" -f7,8') . '</b>' . $br .
    $br .
    'phpversion(): ' . phpversion() . $br .
    $br . $br;


// working with default timezone
print   '<b>Default:</b>' . $br . $br .
    'strftime(%z): ' . strftime("%z", $current_time) . $br .
    'date(O): ' . date("O", $current_time) . $br . $br . $br;

// setting timezone to UTC
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
print   'After <b>date_default_timezone_set(\'UTC\'):</b>' . $br . $br .
    'strftime(%z): ' . strftime("%z", $current_time) . $br .
    'date(O): ' . date("O", $current_time) . $br . $br . $br;
```

Result (on Mac OS X 10.10.5):

```
Script has been executed on 2017.06.12 16:58:04 +0200 (date(O))

ini_get('date.timezone'): Europe/Berlin
date_default_timezone_get(): Europe/Berlin
/etc/localtime: Europe/Moscow

phpversion(): 5.6.2


Default:

strftime(%z): +0400
date(O): +0200


After date_default_timezone_set('UTC'):

strftime(%z): +0300
date(O): +0000
```

Even after setting the timezone to UTC with *date_default_timezone_set()*, two different functions give different timezones.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://3v4l.org/2h0Yh). Perhaps it's a bug that only affects your platform.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Strange behavior indeed, this gives me: "+0400" "+0200" "+0300" "+0000" "+0400" "+0200"